# Symfony FormBuilder Query_builder error/warning

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

I am using the query_builder in the formBuilder to get 'forms' from the DB. When I use this query

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('f')
                            ->select('f');
                    },
```

it works. But then the options list contains all forms. But the forms can have revisions so what I want to do is to get only the last revision from each form and show that in the options list.
To do this, I changed the query to this

```
 'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('f')
                            ->select('f, MAX(f.revisionNumber) as max_revision')
                            ->groupBy('f.name');
                    },
```

But with this query I get the following error/warning

```
Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given
```

What does this mean and how can I solve it?

Comment: Try `select('f.name`

Comment: Still get the same error

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question yesterday:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544654/query-builder-symfony-form-builder-error/33546605

Comment: I did, but that question was never answered with a working solution

Comment: The accepted answer to your question from yesterday should work here too.

Comment: I forgot to mention that your solution worked, but it didn't do exactly what I wanted to do and that was to get the max revision number. When I add the max select to your solution, I still get the error. I'm sorry, should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer!

This is the query I had to use to make it work the way I wanted.

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('f')
                            ->select('f')
                            ->where('f.revisionNumber = (SELECT MAX(f2.revisionNumber) FROM AppBundle:Form f2 WHERE f.formKey = f2.formKey GROUP BY f2.formKey)')
                        ;
                        return $qb;
                    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this

```
$orderObj = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('') # your repositery ex (StackOrdersBundle:PurchaseOrder)
    ->createQueryBuilder('f')
    ->select('f.name, MAX(f.revisionNumber) as max_revision')
    ->where('') # add if want or remove
    ->groupBy(f.name)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Comment: But this is for in the controller right? I need to get a form field with that data so I have to do it in the formType.

Comment: ya this is in controller